# Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.15.0/allure-2.15.0.zip

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, allure

I just started getting acquainted with the tests. The test itself is running, now we need a report, for this I wanted to use Allure. I did everything as on the official website, but this error constantly crashes. In addition, the allure-results folder is not created, I have been tormented by this question for the whole day. I looked at all the tutorials and forums, but the solution to the problem did not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>studentwork</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>9</target>
                    <source>9</source>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/target/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertiesFilePath>${project.build.directory}/src/test/resources/allure.properties</propertiesFilePath>
                    <reportVersion>2.15.0</reportVersion>
                    <reportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/target/allure-report</reportDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.8.0</reportVersion>
                    <allureDownloadUrl>https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/%s/allure-%s.zip</allureDownloadUrl>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Error.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- allure-maven:2.8:report (default-cli) @ studentwork ---
[INFO] Allure installation directory C:\Users\KP\studentwork/.allure
[INFO] Try to finding out allure 2.15.0
[INFO] Downloading allure commandline...
[INFO] Proxy is not specified.
[ERROR] Can't install allure
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.15.0/allure-2.15.0.zip
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1528)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at java.net.URL.openStream (URL.java:1167)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile (FileUtils.java:1126)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureCommandline.download (AllureCommandline.java:126)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureGenerateMojo.installAllure (AllureGenerateMojo.java:172)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureGenerateMojo.executeReport (AllureGenerateMojo.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate (AbstractMavenReport.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute (AbstractMavenReport.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

Comment: The issue is that bintray is not available anymore...

Comment: You have allure plugins in both `build` and `reporting`. Try to merge them into a single configuration under `reporting`.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened for me, please use 2.14 version and mention the allure property in your resource folder.

**POM :**

```
 <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>2.14.0</allure.version>
</properties>
```

**PROPERTY :**
[image]

**Your Output :**

[image]